# Creating a p2p-network with TCP/IP and Akka Streams

Tags: java, scala, sockets, tcp, stream

I am currently dabbling in programming the network layer of a p2p-application in Scala with Akka-Streams 1.0.

I have a Tcp-Server-Binding, realized as a class. Each instantiation (binding to an IP:port) produces a stream of "IncomingConnection"s.
I also have a Tcp-Client-Object which produces a stream of "OutgoingConnection"s as a result to given new addresses (targets).
For either, the BidiFlow from Framing.simpleFramingProtocol gets joined to the flow so I have messages to work with.

Each of those RunnableFlows is a "MyAppConnection", so that I am able to just send/receive Frames regardless of whether it is out- or ingoing.

I am able to send and receive over this construct. But now I would like to
dynamically choose my destination (from within each node), and if there's no connection open already, have it open a new one. How would I realize this with backpressure remaining intact?

My idea was to create a mutable Map, where new connections get added and dead connections get removed. But isn't there a less messy pattern for that? Also I'm not sure how to preserve streams-backpressure with this approach.

FlexiRoute is out of the question, since once the Flow is made runnable, its immutable. Hence I need to know beforehand how many peers I'm talking to. Which might change at any given moment.

Here a little drawing:

```
      ----------------  -----------  -------
    ~>| |            |~>|         |~>|     |~> (out)
      | | Connection |  | Framing |  | MSG |
    <~| |            |<~|         |<~|     |<~ (in)
      ----------------  -----------  -------

                  MyAppConnection
```

Here the MSG stage provides both Source and Sink for the Flow while Connection (regardless of IncomingConnection or OutgoingConnection) is just crosswired to Framing.simpleFramingProtocol to provide the programmatical endpoint for my Flow.

Now imagine having 10 of those; 5 minutes later 15; 5 minutes later just 8.